# Alphanumeric sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, sqlcode

For a single `id` column, we have sequence number 01, 02, 03 upto 99 repeating twice /thrice.

Example:

```
ID SEQ_NO
----------
2   01
2   02
2   03
.
.
.
2   99
2   01 
2   02
2   99
```

We have a requirement to add `AA` prefix to second time when it is looping on `seq_no`, and for third time it should be `BB`.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: I would suggest not doing that, consider the rules for data normalisation and keep your values discreet in separate columns. I would also not store a sequence *number* as (presumably) a *varchar* and instead prefix a leading zero in the application if required.

Comment: So the 27th time around, you use `ZZ` as your prefix - and then what for the 28th time?? Seems a very odd requirement / prefixing strategy.....

Comment: @Stu .. I do agree but we want to make changes in existing system

Comment: @marc_s For now we need only upto 27th time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

If you want only to select SEQ_NO as a new column:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, SEQ_NO ORDER BY SEQ_NO) rn 
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT ID, SEQ_NO,
       CASE 
         WHEN rn>1 THEN
          CONCAT(CHAR(rn+63), CHAR(rn+63), SEQ_NO) 
         ELSE SEQ_NO
       END AS new_seq
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn <= 27
ORDER BY ID, new_seq
```

If you want to update the SEQ_NO column:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, SEQ_NO ORDER BY SEQ_NO) rn 
  FROM table_name
)
UPDATE CTE SET SEQ_NO = CONCAT(CHAR(rn+63), CHAR(rn+63), SEQ_NO) 
        
WHERE rn > 1 AND rn <= 27
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Yi7U_Nu) with a set of data where seq (01 - 10) is repeated three times.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I will go through the demo also